# Rect Styleguidist: Unexpected token import

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-styleguidist

I'm having a problem getting the webpack configuration inside the **styleguide.config.js**

This is my styleguide.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  title: 'My Guide Project',
  components: 'src/components/**/[A-Z]*.js',
  showSidebar: true,
  pagePerSection: true,
  sections: [
    {
      name: 'Components',
      components: () => [
        './src/components/Card/index.js',
      ],
      exampleMode: 'hide', // 'hide' | 'collapse' | 'expand'
      usageMode: 'expand'
    },
  ],
  webpackConfig: require('./tools/webpack.config.js'), <-- Webpack config
}
```

But when I run the npx styleguidist server command, I get the following error in the console:

> Unexpected token import

The error occurs because it accesses to **webpack.config.js** and does not interpret ***"import"*** at the beginning of the file.

This is the first lines of **webpack.config.js**

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import AssetsPlugin from 'assets-webpack-plugin';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';
...
...
```

Can someone help me with this?

I look in a lot of forums and some say that you have to configure a **.babelrc** but I haven't got that file in my project.

> **UPDATE**

This is the **index.js** file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import s from './Card.css';

class Card extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      title,
      titleIconClass,
      showCardAction,
      loading,
      cardHeaderLink,
      iconCustomStyles,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={s.smgCard}>
        <div
          className={`${s.smgCardHeader} ${
            cardHeaderLink ? s.cursorPointer : null
          }`}
          onClick={() => console.log("TEST!")}
          role="presentation"
        >
          <div className={s.smgCardTitle}>
            <span className={s.smgCardTitleText}>{title}</span>
            <i className={`${s.smgCardIcon} ${titleIconClass}`} style={ iconCustomStyles }/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(Card);
```

The error occurs when try to inject styles CSS through **withStyles**

Comment: You need to use babel to transpile the `import` statements to `require`. Or if you don't want to use `import` just simply modify your imports to `const path = require('path');` etc..

Comment: Hi, I included `const path = request('path');` etc.. for each import and now I have this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at WithStyles.componentWillMount` which cames from the following line: 
`this.removeCss = this.context.insertCss.apply(undefined, styles);`

Comment: it's `require` and not `request`. And this error message means that `insertCss` is undefined. You need to debug it where you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Styleguidist doesn't support ECMAScript modules (`import`) in webpack config, so you need to use `require` instead:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
```

P. S. As far as I see [webpack doesn't support](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration/) it by default either.